# Make an R script write lines to the console faster (Rgui)

Tags: r, rgui

I've written quite a large R script (1000+ lines). Currently there is a `rm(list=ls())` statement at the top of the script, as I need to test how it runs cleanly.

I run the code by `ctrl + A`, `ctrl + R`
The problem is is that this seems to take a long time in the Rgui to write each line to the console before running it. I feel R should be able to write to the the console faster than this and was wondering if there is a faster way to run a script.

(ie hide the lines written to the console and just run the script)

Comment: If you just want to r script, you can run from the terminal. `Rscript your_script.R`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way is to simply source the document. If you have it saved then just type `source("FullPathOfmyfile.R")` and it will run without printing the commands, it will only print the output and print statements. Alternatively you can set `echo = FALSE`.